# Custom site column is in the list view, but is missing in newform.aspx

Tags: list, custom-list, people-picker, site-column

I've created a list programmatically with two site columns (title, name (peoplepicker))

[image]

The list show both site columns but when I try to create a new item only the title will show, "name" (people picker) are missing. It's not a content type!

[image]

Code for creating the fields:

```
<Fields>
  <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" />
  <Field ID="{12B2742C-2A44-4792-935C-5504B1CC2198}" Type="User" DisplayName="Name" List="UserInfo" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" UserSelectionScope="0" ShowField="ImnName" UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly" StaticName="Name1" Name="Name1" />
</Fields>
```

views example:

```
   <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Name1"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
```

EventReciever:

```
            if (importantRolesList != null)
            {

                SPList oList = web.Lists[ImportantRolesListName];
                SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();
                oSPListItem["Title"] = "testitem";
                oSPListItem.Update();


                var importantrolesWP = new XsltListViewWebPart
                {
                    Title = ImportantRolesListName,
                    ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleAndBorder,
                    ListName = importantRolesList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
                    ViewGuid = importantRolesList.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
                };



                webPartManager.AddWebPart(importantrolesWP, RightZoneId, 3);
            }
```

Comment: Please provide the code which is used for the list creation.

Comment: You need to add the field reference to the content type of the list.

Comment: It's not a contenttype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my listdefinition (schema.xml) I had some CT's. Like

```
<ContentTypes>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
    <Folder TargetName="Item" />
  </ContentTypeRef>
  <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
</ContentTypes>
```

This was added when I used the "wizzard" in visual studio, where I added custom list.

just remove all those if you don't have an CT, like so

```
<ContentTypes>
</ContentTypes>
```

This solved my problem, all site columns does now show in newform

IF you have added the site column to a CT, remember to put it inside

Comment: This should be documented by Microsoft somewhere but its really hard to find it. But it worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute     `ShowInNewForm = "true"` to your Field-Definition (Field ID=....)

Reference :    http://jasear.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/sharepoint-2010-list-fields-not-showing-up-in-edit-display-or-new-forms/

Comment: Doesn't work. PeoplePicker may cause the problem.

Comment: is there a reason why you can't do it via list settings?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your field to the content type. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/01/20/why-do-my-new-list-fields-not-appear-on-the-new-edit-or-display-forms.aspx) for more details. It describes your issue.